# How do I create a rollover counter within a list in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, list, counter

I need to build a rollover counter within a list in python. Given a starting list of a variable length startlist, and all terms minnum, the counter should increment index 0 by one until it reaches maxnum, at which point index 0 resets to minnum and index one increments by one. This continues until all terms of the list are maxnum, at which point the loop should end. Here is an example.
`minnum = 1, maxnum = 2, startlist = [1, 1, 1]` The counting begins. `[1, 1, 1] -> [2, 1, 1] -> [1, 2, 1] -> [2, 2, 1] -> [1, 1, 2] -> [2, 1, 2] -> [1, 2, 2] -> [2, 2, 2] -> end`

I have tried a lot of code but nothing seems to work. If someone could please help me out with this that would be much appreciated.

Comment: "I have tried a lot of code" such as?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools#module-itertools):

```
from itertools import product

def main():
    minimum = 1
    maximum = 2
    num_counters = 3

    # Build the counter values iterable object
    counter_range = range(minimum, maximum+1)

    # Build the cartesian product of your counters.
    # You have to reverse the generated tuples to make it match your requirements
    counters = [tuple(reversed(x)) for x in product(counter_range, repeat=num_counters)]
    print(counters)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

```
[(1, 1, 1), (2, 1, 1), (1, 2, 1), (2, 2, 1), (1, 1, 2), (2, 1, 2), (1, 2, 2), (2, 2, 2)]
```